# Access VBA: Editing a RecordSet in a continuous subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I am trying to write a function to loop through the records in a continuous subform and clear the value in a specific field (Entity_Under_Consideration, which is a lookup field represented by a combobox on the subform) for every record.

The following does not work. It doesn't throw any errors either. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
Public Function clearEUCData(subform As Control)

    'take a clone of the subform's recordset
    Dim entityRecSet As Recordset
    Set entityRecSet = subform.Form.Recordset.Clone()

    'if there are any records in the subform...
    If entityRecSet.RecordCount > 0 Then

        'start with the first record
        entityRecSet.MoveFirst

        'iterate through each row, clearing the data in the EUC field
        Do Until entityRecSet.EOF

            With entityRecSet
                .Edit
                    Entity_Under_Consideration = 0
                .Update
            End With

        entityRecSet.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If

    'close and purge the cloned recordset
    entityRecSet.Close
    Set entityRecSet = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: You don't appear to be refreshing the forms recordset after updating the cloned recordset?

Comment: And yet the changes are still being applied to the form's recordset. How is that happening?

Comment: Ninja access gnomes working in the background? Often recordset updates do show up immediately, just not always... May well depend on if it's a local table or how a linked table is connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to be more explicit:

```
With entityRecSet
    .Edit
        .Fields("Entity_Under_Consideration").Value = 0
    .Update
End With
```

Comment: It is best practice to add `Option Explicit` to all code modules.  That option would have caused an error with the undeclared variable `Entity_Under_Consideration`.  In the VBA IDE, you can also set `Tools | Options | Editor | Code Settings | [x] Require Variable Declarations` which will automatically add Option Explicit to all new code modules.